# Inkscape's SVG file: location path for an imported figure

Tags: svg, inkscape

`Inkscape` is a really good tool for importing `PDF` or `EPS` scientific plots into a blank page, and then place arrows on top of the graphs, text, make scientific drawings assemble them in the desired location and then save as a unique PDF page that can then be included as a `figure` in a `latex` document.

A project in `Inkscape` can be saved not only as pdf, but also as a `.svg` file. This file can be opened with any text editor, e.g. `vim` or `gedit`. All the information on the project is saved in this file.

Most of the times I need to continue working over the original PDF plots that I once imported into a inkscape project I made back in time. As far as I am concerned, there is no option in the inkscape interface that allows you to know which is the original location path of the pdf figure that was once imported into the inkscape project. For instance, right clicking on the figure and opening the `Object Properties`, or double clicking the figure and examining the `Objects` subpanel that is opened in the right hand side does not inform about the desired location path.

I am sure there is somewhere in the `.svg` file where it is written the path for an imported pdf figure. However, the language in which the `svg` file is written is new for me.

In Inkscape, how can I know the location path of an imported figure?
or where is stored in the `svg` file the location path of an imported figure?

As a MWE, I have created with `inkscape` a `svg` file that contains only one PDF plot. This file is 393 lines, so it makes it a bit difficult to copy-paste here. Thus, the following is the link to this `svg` file:
http://www.mediafire.com/file/2ad1rur89251vim/fit1_presentation.svg

Answer (score 1):

The original location of that PDF is not stored in the SVG file anywhere.

But here's my suggestion, of how you can record it, in an easily accessible place, for later retrieval.

1. After importing a PDF, select all the newly added objects and group them (Ctrl-G).
2. Open the XML editor if it isn't already open (Shft-Ctrl-X)
3. The group you just created should already be selected.  You should see that it has an 'id' attribute. Click on the `id` row in the top right of the XML editor.
4. Enter the original URL or path of the PDF into the id value box underneath.
5. Click Set.

[image: Inkscape XML editor]

In the future, if you need to find the path, of the PDF, just select the correct group. Open the XML editor again, and voila.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and efforts. I would like to stress that the aim behind achieving this is just to know the location of the original PDF, because then you can go to the python or gnuplot source file, normally located in the same folder where the PDF is created, and modify the plot accordingly, and then import it again into the inkscape project.

Comment: For example, if this multi PDF plots assemble project was made in *tex, the location path of all the plots would be perfectly identified, i.e. in the `\includegraphics` line

Comment: Thus, this means that after importing an image, you have to remember that the immediate following operation is to follow steps `1` to `5` in order to keep track of where the original PDF plot is located. This is a bit tedious.

Comment: I am wondering if there is a way to tell inkscape that everytime a new figure or plot is imported, automatically modify that `id` with the path from which you are loading the figure?

Comment: Not that I know of. But you could write (or pay someone to write) an [Inkscape extension](https://inkscape.org/en/gallery/%3Dextension/) to do this, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the information isn't there. The import process is destructive in the sense that you cannot recreate the original file from the produced .svg file, and the Inkscape developers seem to have reasoned that this meant preserving a reference to the original file made no sense.

The nearest to what you are searching for you'll find if you open a PDF with Inkscape (as opposed to opening an empty file and importing the PDF). If you then open Edit -> XML Editor, you will find an attribute `sodipodi:docname` on the top level `<svg>` element, containing the original name of the opened file, sans path. Unfortunately, as soon as you save your project as .svg, the file name is overwritten.

The best you can do is save the original file information by hand as part of the document. Since SVG is an XML format, you are more or less free to choose an element/attribute of your liking for that, as long as either it isn't in the `svg` namespace (thus becoming part of the grafical format browsers and other renderers try to interpret) or has meaning in the `inkscape` or `sodipodi` namespace (which inkscape uses to save information pertaining to its UI).

What comes to mind for storing the file information, even if it is more creative than standard-conformant, is this: Open File -> Document properties and choose the "Metadata" tab. Using the "Source" field to enter the file name is a bit of misappropriation, but not too far from the [intended content](http://dublincore.org/documents/2012/06/14/dcmi-terms/#terms-source), as long as the file is on your own computer. But you should be aware that the information is stored in such a way that it may be read by web crawlers when published on the internet, or by any program looking for rdf/Dublin Core metadata.

In the file, you will find the information as

```
<svg>
  <metadata>
    <rdf:rdf>
      <cc:Work>
        ...
        <dc:source>/path/to/file.pdf</dc:source>
      ...
```

In a more free-form approach, you could use the [`<desc>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#DescElement) element to associate the file path with the topmost element of your imported PDF - that would work with multiple imported files. You can set it with the "Description" entry of the Object properties dialogue, and it will be a direct child element of the element you set it for. The SVG spec makes no restriction what may be the content of that element.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, the `.svg` project contains normally more than one pdf plot, and your approach seems to work only for identifying the path of one original plot ? Is there a way to writing the path of all the plots in the project? In the question, you can find the link for a `svg` project with two pdf plots in it. Thanks again.

Comment: As I said, my recomendation is more creative than following any standard. You are free to write anything into an XML file you like as long as it does not interfere with a program that interprets content. You could write multiple file paths in one element, you could invent a name for another element or attribute, it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Menu: File -> Document Properties (or use Ctrl+Shift+D shortcut)

Tab: Metadata

Field: Source

Is it there?

For your file it is:

```
/home/david/fit1.pdf
```

Comment: No, the information is not there when you import the figure. It is only when writing it down manually that is there